# Passing pointers to arrays to functions

Tags: c

I am storing my information in an array of pointers to structs.  In other words, each element of the array is a pointer to a linked list.

I don't know how long the array should be, so instead of initializing the array in my main() function, I instead intialize the double pointer

```
struct graph** graph_array;
```

Then once I obtain the length of the array, I try to initialize each element of graph_array using a function GraphInitialize:

```
int GraphInitialize(struct graph* *graph_array,int vertices)
{ 
  struct graph* graph_array2[vertices+1];
  graph_array = graph_array2;
  int i;

  for (i=0;i<vertices+1;i++)
  {
    graph_array[i] = NULL;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But for some reason this is not returning the updated graph_array to main().  Basically, this function is updating graph_array locally, and no change is being made.  As a result, any time I try to access an element of graph_array it seg faults because it is not initialized.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Following the convo with Tom Ahh I should add something else that makes this more confusing.

I don't call GraphIntialize directly from main().  Instead, I call getdata() from main, and pass a pointer to graph_array to getdata as shown below.

```
    getdata(argc, argv, vertpt, edgept, &graph_array)

    int getdata(int argc, char *argv[], int *verts, int *edges, struct graph* **graph_array)
```

Then getdata gets the number of vertices from my input file, and uses that to call GraphInitialize:

```
    if ((GraphInitialize(&graph_array, *verts)) == -1)
    {
      printf("GraphCreate failed");
      return 0;
    }
```

This results in an error: "expected 'struct graph 3ASTERISKS' but argument is of type 'struct graph 4ASTERISKS'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign something to `graph_array`, you simply assign it to its local copy. The changes made to it in the function will not be see-able by the caller. You need to pass it by pointer value to be able to change its value. Change your function prototype to `int GraphInitialize(struct graph ***graph_array,int vertices)` and when you call it, use `GraphInitialize(&graph_array, 42)`.

Second problem in your code is when you create `graph_array2`, you declare it to be local to your `GraphInitialize()` function. Thus, when exiting your function, graph_array2 is destroyed, even if you assigned it to `*graph_array`. (the star dereferences the pointer to assign it to the value it points to).

change your assignation to `*graph_array = malloc(sizeof(*graph_array) * vertices);` and you should be fine.

Comment: Why is the malloc'ing any different?  Aren't both examples of allocating memory?

Comment: First allocates the memory on the stack, second on the heap. Stack is local to the function, it is *destroyed* when the function exit. Second is managed by the user, and memory is *destroyed* when you explicitly call `free()`

Comment: I tried this, and got the following error: warning: passing argument 1 of 'GraphInitialize' from incompatible pointer type note: expected 'struct graph ***' but argument is of type 'struct graph ****' very confused.

Comment: Is the declaration of `graph_array` the same as you wrote in your question ?

Comment: Yes.  Well, I'm trying to create an abstract data type, so I declare it as that and then set graph_array = GraphCreate(); where GraphCreate is of type struct graph**.  The GraphCreate function is just struct graph** p = NULL; return p;

Comment: Can you add the calling function to `GraphInitialize` to your question ? Or pastebin it in a comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20205/discussion-between-ed-cota-and-tom-ahh)

Answer (score 2):

Memory is divided into two parts, the stack and the heap. Malloc will give you back a chunk of memory from the heap, which lives on between functions, but must be freed. Thus your program must be careful to keep track of the malloced() memory and call free() on it.

Declaring a variable graph_array2[vertices+1] allocates a local variable on the stack. When the function returns the stack pointer is popped "freeing" the memory allocated in the function call. You don't have to manage the memory manually, but when the function call is over it no longer exists.

See here for some discussion of the two allocation styles:
http://www.ucosoft.com/stack-vs-heap.html

Answer (score 1):

You're using C99-style local array allocation.   The array disappears when the function returns.  Instead you need to use `malloc()` to allocate memory that will persist after the function.  You can use `typedefs` to make your code more readable:

```
typedef struct graph_node_s {  // linked list nodes
  struct graph_node_s *next;
   ...
} GRAPH_NODE;

typedef GRAPH_NODE *NODE_REF;  // reference to node
typedef NODE_REF *GRAPH;       // var length array of reference to node

GRAPH AllocateGraph(int n_vertices)
{
  int i;
  GRAPH g;

  g = malloc(n_vertices * sizeof(NODE_REF));
  if (!g) 
    return NULL;
  for (i = 0; i < n_vertices; i++)
    g[i] = NULL;
  return g;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.

First, `graph_array2` has *auto extent*, meaning that it only exists within its enclosing scope, which is the body of the `GraphInitialize` function; once the function exits, that memory is released, and `graph_array` is no longer pointing anywhere meaningful.

Second, any changes to the parameter `graph_array` are local to the function; the changes won't be reflected in the caller.  Remember, all parameters are passed *by value*; if you pass a pointer to a function, and you want the value of the pointer to be modified by the function, you must pass a pointer to the pointer, like so:

```
void foo(int **p)
{
  *p = some_new_pointer_value();
  return;
}

int main(void)
{
  int *ptr = NULL;
  foo(&ptr);
  ...
}
```

If you intend for `InitializeGraph` to allocate the memory for your array, you'll need to do something like this:

```
int InitializeGraph(struct graph ***graph_array, int vertices)
{
  *graph_array = malloc(sizeof **graph_array * vertices);
  if (*graph_array)
  {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < vertices; i++)
    {
      (*graph_array}[i] = NULL; // parentheses matter here!
    }
  }
  else
  {
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  int v;
  struct graph **arr;
  ...
  if (GraphInitialize(&arr, v) == 0)
  {
    // array has been allocated and initialized.
  }
  ...
}
```

Postfix operators like `[]` have higher precedence than unary operators like `*`, so the expression `*arr[i]` is interpreted as `*(arr[i])`; we're dereferencing the `i`'th element of the array.  In `GraphInitialize`, we need to dereference `graph_array` *before* subscripting (`graph_array` isn't an array, it *points* to an array), so we need to write `(*graph_array)[i]`.

Comment: Alright, I tried this, and got the following error:

warning: passing argument 1 of 'GraphInitialize' from incompatible pointer type

note: expected 'struct graph ***' but argument is of type 'struct graph ****'

very confused.